# How to create a SharePoint Choice field with 'Allow fill in choice' set to 'true'?

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-rest-api, spfx, spfx-webparts, modern-experience

I am trying to create a choice field in SP list from my SPFx Web Part.

I want to set 'Allow fill in choice' is equal to `true`. But after research I am still not able to find out how to set 'Allow fill in choice' choice to true from REST call.

Please find below code which works fine to create the field:

```
    url: https://test.sharepoint.com/sites/dev/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('MyList')/fields
    const response = await fetch(url, {
       method: 'POST',
       credentilas: 'include',
       headers: {
           Accept: 'application/json;odata=verbose',
           'Content-Type': 'application/json;odata=nometadadat',
           'x-RequestDigest': xRequestDigestValue
       },
       body: JSON.stringyfy({
          Required: true,
          FiledTypeKind: 6,
          Title: 'MyChoice'
       })
    }
```

Could you please let me know how to set 'Allow fill-in choice' to 'true'?

Comment: try code given in my answer. let me know if it works or you come across any issue.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the FillInChoice property to true.

Here is the documentation for the property.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/sharepoint-csom/ee539355(v=office.15)

Here is the FieldChoice object in Fiddler for a field that has this property enabled.

[image: FieldChoice JSON]

Since you're using `odata=verbose`, you'll also need to set the metadata for the object you're passing in the body of the request. Try changing it to

```
  body: JSON.stringyfy({
    "__metadata": {
      "type": "SP.FieldChoice"
    },
    Required: true,
    FiledTypeKind: 6,
    FillInChoice: true,
    Title: 'MyChoice'
  })
```

You'll also need to add the choices to the object being passed in the body of the request.

Comment: Yes, I have tried with that. If I provide FillInChoice: true in body. It is throwing bad request(404 error)

Comment: I updated my answer with additional detail.

Comment: Hi Rob, I have found FillInChoice only allowed in update. So, if I update the field after creating it, It does work. And also I have tried with __metadata and same 400 error was coming. So what I came to conclusion like, to set FillInChoice to true we have update the filed after creating it and pass FillInChoice: true in body with separate REST call to update the filed. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Here is the working code I tried to create a choice field with Fill-in choices allowed using SharePoint REST API:

**HTML**:

```
<button type="button" onclick="createField()"> Create Choice Field </button>
```

**JS**:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/sites/SPConnect/SiteAssets/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function createField() {
        var fieldEndpoint = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('List Name')/fields";

        $.ajax({
            url: fieldEndpoint,
            type: "POST",
            data: JSON.stringify({
                '__metadata': { 'type': 'SP.FieldChoice' },
                'FieldTypeKind': 6,
                'Title': 'Scope',
                'Choices': {
                    '__metadata': { 'type': 'Collection(Edm.String)' },
                    'results': [ 'Internal', 'External' ]
                },
                'FillInChoice': true
            }),
            headers: {
                "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val(),
                "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
                "content-type": "application/json;odata=verbose"
            },
            success: function (data) {
                console.log("Field created successfully");
            },
            error: function (error) {
                console.log(error);
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

**Output (Field Settings)**:

[image]

**Output (Fill-in choice added to list item)**:

[image]

**official documentation**: [Fields REST API reference](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/sharepoint-rest-reference/dn600182(v=office.15))